# Multiple Navigation Options

Tags: navigation

I'm facig kind of a problem having to many navigation layers, my next step it's to try to reagroup some tabs but basically my client wants something like that.

What do you think about it? any ideas?

in goes like that:

sidebar with icons --> top tabs ---> sidebar with buttons (kind of the main navigation) ---> tabs (inside button) ----> submenu

Thanks!

[image: wireframe]

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange. Posts that solicit general feedback/reviews are off-topic but you are welcome to edit your question to tell us what specific problem you're having with this design. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more information about the context of the app/site, the IA, available menu items, workflow for the user and the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be lot of navigation at lot of places. Not sure of the reason of the complete ask, but if I assume that there are multiple nodes of menu->submenu->sub-sub-menu->sub-sub-sub-menu , having multiple places of navigation wont be a good user experience. Below are soome food for ideas:

1.Use icons on the left side bar as main menu items-> make the icons expandable vertically to see sub menu -> sub menu when clicked can expand further vertically down or you can have another bar appearing after the main bar.
Combinine sub menu with smaller tabs (not a great experience though), Definetly have a search option if the menu is reaaly huge infinite vertical scroll.

2.Grouping always helps. You can have whole vertical menu tab as one icon (see image below)
see the attached image below[image]

Now if you see icons on top, these are baskets I am talking about. so make baskets, use icons on menu to reduce width of menu bar

Hope this helps

Comment: having a combination of tab and vertically expanding menu is fine as long as the tabs are not more than 3-4 sub menus

Comment: cool, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

In some cases I see people with similar problems doing megamenus or arranged menu items. That means that specially for ecommerce websites they will have the waterfall menu for the same type of categories.

In your case I believe there could be a solution to try and rearrange the items in menu and their paths. Maybe some items could be placed in stack form.

It all actually depends on your user needs and goals. You need to conduct a user research where you would ask your user how would they imagine finding certain information or how would they imagine doing something. Results will be abstract but from that you can easily see in which direction you should move for next step.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in your situation - Simply use the way a user would skim/read through F pattern or Z pattern
[Read more on F pattern, Z pattern](https://99designs.com/blog/tips/visual-hierarchy-landing-page-designs/)

a. Keep your top bar as the main menu [any hierarchy here is beneficial if you need to go secondary or tertiary level] that provides horizontal movement firstly

b. Now keep your page below the top bar as one section held up by the top bar. The contextual menu will sit here on to the left. This follows 'F' pattern where user will skim and move down from horizontal layer to vertical direction. Anything happening within the contextual space will be readily supported by 'Contextual menu'.